# How to get a Cookie from a composable in Nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I'm trying to access an auth token stored inside a cookie or localStorage from a composable.

```js
// composables/useUser.ts
export const useUser = () => {
  const info = async () => {
    const config = useRuntimeConfig();

    try {
      const token = localStorage.getItem("auth_token");

      const { data } = await useFetch(
        `${config.public.baseURL}/users/info`,
        {
          method: "GET",
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
        }
      );

      const info = data.value.user;

      localStorage.setItem("user", info);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
};
```

I have to specify `process.client` to be able to access the document or the localStorage, which is not suitable for my case.